# how to change value of a button on click

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the value of a button when onclick. so far I am able to get that working but i would like it to change back to the original value when click again. any suggestions?

my code:

```
{if $activity_count > "0"}
<input onclick="change()" type="button" class="rbutton" value="Show/Hide" id="show_act" />

{literal}
  <script>
   function change()
 {
  document.getElementById("show_act").value="Hide/Show"; 

}
 </script>
{/literal}

{else}
      {/if}
```

Comment: So check value, if X, set it to Y.

Comment: Save old value, then use toggle function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a flag:

```
var state = true;
```

Then modify your change function to toggle the state and do the appropriate update based on the state:

```
function change()
{
  var textValue = state ? "Hide/Show" : "Show/Hide";   // select the value based on the state
  document.getElementById("show_act").value=textValue; // apply the value
  state = !state;                                      // toggle the state for the next click
}
```

Here is a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/7kxA8/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i was not able to get this to toggle well.

Comment: How come, what was the problem?

Comment: sorry i take that back. i did not include var stat = true;

Comment: Yes, that's the key line here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("show_act").value = (document.getElementById("show_act").value == "Show") ? "Hide" : "Show";
```

This one line code is enough within **change()** function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that will have a button that says hello and goodbye when it is clicked.  The variable is a bit challenging to call with the variable as document.getElementById("show_act").  In this case, the submit button has an ID called "show_act" so be sure you keep track of what you name it.  Good luck in your programming!

```
<script>
function change(id,text1,text2){
    if(document.getElementById(id).value == text1) document.getElementById(id).value = text2;
    else document.getElementById(id).value = text1;
}
</script>
<input onClick="change('show_act','Show','Hide');" type="button" class="rbutton" value="Show" id="show_act" />
```

Comment: Do not teach people to use globals, ever! And why couldn't you write an example from what OP has (using OPs original markup)?

Comment: Edited answer to avoid globals and to use markup in format more similar to original poster.

Comment: +1 Much better! Sorry if I sounded too harsh in that original comment.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I think I learned something important.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
function change()
{
var element = getdocument.ElemnetById .("show_act");
 element.setAttribute("clicked",true);
if(element.getAttribute("clicked") === 'true'){
element.value="Show/Hide"; 
element.removeAttribute("clicked")
}else {
element.value="Hide/Show"; 
}
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to look up the element on every line?